# How to connect Dart to SQLite?

Tags: sqlite, dart, indexeddb, web-sql

My old application used web2py with SQLite as the database. Now I want to try porting this app to Dart and again use SQLite as the database.

I can't find any documentation on how to use it.  I just found out how to use MySQL with sqljocky.

I've tried to read the web_sql and indexed_db APIs, but I can't find a way to connect to SQLite.  How can I use SQLite from Dart?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, [dart-sqlite](https://github.com/sam-mccall/dart-sqlite/) is the only public attempt at SQLite bindings for Dart, but it's out of date.  My guess is that it would actually be pretty easy to update the code and get it up-and-running.

`web_sql` and `indexed_db` are both for use in the browser, which, as far as I can tell from your question, isn't what you're looking for.

**Update:** I [updated dart-sqlite](https://github.com/darshan-/dart-sqlite) so that all the tests now pass, at least on my machine.  You're definitely venturing into uncharted territory if you use it, but it's a start.

Comment: Thank you.....Yes. I was try it. But it's not easy for me. I tried financeCoding version too. But still get many error.

Comment: I tried to build your forked version. Here is the issue https://github.com/sam-mccall/dart-sqlite/issues/6 .

Comment: @SunggukLim No, I haven't used it since I posted this.

Comment: @Darshan-JosiahBarber fine. I'll try this